# Настройка картинки при шаринге в соцсетях

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, facebook, facebook-api, соцсети

Как настроить конкретную картинку под каждую страницу своего сайта при шаринге в разных соцсетях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял то вам нужно использовать мета-теги og:*, вот тут можете почитать и найти примеры http://ogp.me/ (Английский)

Вот пример изменения картинки

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />`

P.s  Некоторые сервисы могут кешировать данные мета-теги и для обновления информации о странице с изменённым тегом нужно обратится к специальному API методу (в случае Вк)